# Parse a txt file into a csv

Tags: python, csv, parsing

I have this large text file that keeps on repeating like this

```
[Event "Rated Crazyhouse game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/NsNeyqv1"]
[Date "2018.01.23"]
[Round "-"]
[White "nikoskaterini"]
[Black "Ominous"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2018.01.23"]
[UTCTime "18:22:39"]
[WhiteElo "1611"]
[BlackElo "2118"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-10"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+2"]
[Variant "Crazyhouse"]
[TimeControl "30+0"]
[ECO "?"]
[Opening "?"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. d4 { [%clk 0:00:30] } d5 { [%clk 0:00:30] } 2. Bf4 { [%clk 0:00:27] } Nc6 { [%clk 0:00:30] } 3. e3 { [%clk 0:00:26] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:00:30] } 4. Bd3 { [%clk 0:00:25] } Bg4 { [%clk 0:00:30] } 5. c3 { [%clk 0:00:25] } Bxd1 { [%clk 0:00:29] } 6. Kxd1 { [%clk 0:00:24] } e6 { [%clk 0:00:28] } 7. Nd2 { [%clk 0:00:23] } Bd6 { [%clk 0:00:28] } 8. Bxd6 { [%clk 0:00:21] } cxd6 { [%clk 0:00:28] } 9. Ngf3 { [%clk 0:00:19] } O-O { [%clk 0:00:27] } 10. Ng5 { [%clk 0:00:17] } B@e4 { [%clk 0:00:27] } 11. Bxe4 { [%clk 0:00:14] } dxe4 { [%clk 0:00:27] } 12. B@e2 { [%clk 0:00:11] } B@f5 { [%clk 0:00:27] } 13. Nh3 { [%clk 0:00:08] } Bxh3 { [%clk 0:00:24] } 14. gxh3 { [%clk 0:00:08] } N@d3 { [%clk 0:00:23] } 15. Rg1 { [%clk 0:00:08] } Nxf2+ { [%clk 0:00:22] } 16. Ke1 { [%clk 0:00:06] } Nd3+ { [%clk 0:00:22] } 17. Bxd3 { [%clk 0:00:05] } exd3 { [%clk 0:00:20] } 18. B@h6 { [%clk 0:00:04] } Q@e2# { [%clk 0:00:18] } 0-1


[Event "Rated Crazyhouse game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/0r8jJe5d"]
[Date "2018.01.23"]
[Round "-"]
[White "RefuteMeThisWaste"]
[Black "Ominous"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2018.01.23"]
[UTCTime "15:51:19"]
[WhiteElo "1718"]
[BlackElo "2115"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-23"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+3"]
[Variant "Crazyhouse"]
[TimeControl "300+0"]
[ECO "?"]
[Opening "?"]
[Termination "Time forfeit"]

1. e4 { [%clk 0:05:00] } e5 { [%clk 0:05:00] } 2. Bc4 { [%clk 0:04:58] } Bc5 { [%clk 0:04:58] } 3. Nf3 { [%clk 0:04:50] } Nc6 { [%clk 0:04:56] } 4. Bxf7+ { [%clk 0:04:42] } Kxf7 { [%clk 0:04:55] } 5. d4 { [%clk 0:04:37] } Bxd4 { [%clk 0:04:53] } 6. Ng5+ { [%clk 0:04:27] } Kf8 { [%clk 0:04:46] } 7. Qf3+ { [%clk 0:03:38] } Nf6 { [%clk 0:04:42] } 8. P@d5 { [%clk 0:03:11] } B@g4 { [%clk 0:04:37] } 9. Qa3+ { [%clk 0:02:45] } P@c5 { [%clk 0:04:21] } 10. dxc6 { [%clk 0:02:40] } Bxf2+ { [%clk 0:04:19] } 11. Kxf2 { [%clk 0:02:30] } dxc6 { [%clk 0:04:18] } 12. h3 { [%clk 0:01:41] } Bge6 { [%clk 0:04:06] } 13. B@g4 { [%clk 0:01:00] } Bxg4 { [%clk 0:03:52] } 14. hxg4 { [%clk 0:00:57] } B@d4+ { [%clk 0:03:45] } 15. B@e3 { [%clk 0:00:53] } Nxg4+ { [%clk 0:03:38] } 16. Kf1 { [%clk 0:00:38] } Nxe3+ { [%clk 0:03:34] } 17. Bxe3 { [%clk 0:00:35] } Qf6+ { [%clk 0:03:19] } 18. N@f5 { [%clk 0:00:29] } Bxe3 { [%clk 0:03:14] } 19. Qxe3 { [%clk 0:00:24] } B@d4 { [%clk 0:03:11] } 20. N@e6+ { [%clk 0:00:16] } Bxe6 { [%clk 0:03:09] } 21. Nxe6+ { [%clk 0:00:12] } Qxe6 { [%clk 0:03:08] } 22. B@e7+ { [%clk 0:00:08] } Qxe7 { [%clk 0:03:01] } 23. Nxe7 { [%clk 0:00:07] } P@e2+ { [%clk 0:03:00] } 24. Qxe2 { [%clk 0:00:03] } N@g3+ { [%clk 0:02:59] } 25. Ke1 { [%clk 0:00:01] } B@f2+ { [%clk 0:02:55] } 0-1
```

I would like to convert this into a csv file where "Event", "Site", "date" etc are all headers. Could anyone point me in the right direction on how to get started on this project. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Quick googing for "python lichess" gets me https://github.com/niklasf but I have not examined whether there is actually a parser for this format there (nor do I know if this is actually a format used by lichess actually, I just assumed).

Comment: A bit further prodding suggests that this is called PGN format and that you probably want http://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html

Answer (score 0):

I would use `pandas` for this task:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
games = []
dic = {}
for l in file:
    if l[0] == "[":
        string = l[1:-1]
        header = string.split()[0]
        dic[header] = string[len(header):-2].strip().strip('"')
    if l[0] == "1":
        games.append(dic)
        dic = {}
    else:
        pass

df = pd.DataFrame(games)

df.to_csv('games.csv', index=False)

df1 = pd.read_csv('games.csv')
print(df1)
```

This results in:

```
     Black  BlackElo  BlackRatingDiff        Date ECO                  Event  \
0  Ominous      2118                2  2018.01.23   ?  Rated Crazyhouse game   
1  Ominous      2115                3  2018.01.23   ?  Rated Crazyhouse game   

  Opening Result Round                          Site   Termination  \
0       ?    0-1     -  https://lichess.org/NsNeyqv1        Normal   
1       ?    0-1     -  https://lichess.org/0r8jJe5d  Time forfeit   

  TimeControl     UTCDate   UTCTime     Variant              White  WhiteElo  \
0        30+0  2018.01.23  18:22:39  Crazyhouse      nikoskaterini      1611   
1       300+0  2018.01.23  15:51:19  Crazyhouse  RefuteMeThisWaste      1718   

   WhiteRatingDiff  
0              -10  
1              -23
```